# How to get head data in JOOMLA?

Tags: joomla

Is there any method to get the `<head></head/>` data from `html`? I found only `getHead()`, but it return array of elements. The problem is that i need to check if one of my js scripts is already included. It has a keyword in the name, but i don't have a full path to it.

Comment: Why not create a flag in your component/plugin/local or global registry when it is first loaded and determine this from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try find you script in JDocument object:

```php
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
print_r($doc->_scripts);
```

It contain array with  already added scripts, where the key is a script path.
Of course it works only if the script added using `$doc->addScriptDeclaration();`

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [JDocumentHTML::getHeadData()](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Document.HtmlDocument.html#method_getHeadData) method to retrieve styles scripts and other things from the head as an array.

For example I've used it to remove some weird empty link stylesheet files that were placed in the head but dunno where they came from:

```php
// get current instance of Document object
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

// get the head data (it's returned as an array)
$jhead = $doc->getHeadData();

// remove empty links
unset($jhead["styleSheets"][""]);

//set the new Head array data
$doc->setHeadData($jhead);
```